# Is there a pythonic idiom for changing the normal flow of execution based on a percentage?

Tags: python, random

Edit - I'm making a data generator that allows the users to specify particular fields as optional and the percentage a field returns None instead of a value if the field is optional. In other words, most of the time the function will return the intended value, but if the user wishes to have the function randomly return something abnormal according to a percentage, he may do so.

To generalize what I currently do:

```
import random

def foo(val, pct):
     return val if random.random() < pct else None
```

Is there a standard, pythonic idiom for what I'm trying to accomplish that is immediately recognizable to other programmers?

Comment: It can't be an idiom if it's something nobody ever does. What's your motivation for this?

Comment: @MarkRansom I have a script that randomly generates values and allows the user to specify a field as optional and the percentage a null value should be returned. Perhaps the user wants it to be optional 20%, 50%, or however often.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a decorator especially if you need to do this for a bunch of functions

```
def sometimesNone(pct):
    def wrapper(fn):
        def f(*args, **kw):
            return fn(*args, **kw) if random.random() > pct else None
        return f
    return wrapper

@sometimesNone(pct=0.3)
def foo(val):
     return val
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use-case and whether reusability is your goal, you may want to use a decorator to achieve this:

```
import random

def chaos(chance):
    def wrapper(func):
        def random_none(*args, **kwargs):
            if random.random() > chance:
                return "pizza"
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return random_none
    return wrapper

@chaos(0.7)
def foo(val):
    return val
```

Then you don't have to repeat the chance logic all over the place, if it's common. At this point, of course, you're relying less on idiom and more on hiding the complexity from the end-user in favor of a decorator name that clearly communicates what is going on.

```
>>> import pct
>>> pct.foo("test")
'test'
>>> pct.foo("test")
'test'
>>> pct.foo("test")
'test'
>>> pct.foo("test")
'test'
>>> pct.foo("test")
'pizza'
>>> pct.foo("test")
'test'
>>> pct.foo("test")
'pizza'
>>> pct.foo("test")
'test'
>>> pct.foo("test")
'test'
>>> pct.foo("test")
'test'
>>> pct.foo("test")
'test'
>>> pct.foo("test")
'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that there would be an idiom for this particular scenario, since it's not one that most people are going to use a lot. However, you might like to generalize the functionality of "return one of (f1,f2) with probability (p, 1-p)" 
That would look something like

```
def either (f1, f2, p):
  if random.random() < p:
    return f1
  return f2
```

Notice that I'm returning the function itself, not the value - this makes it a little easier to deal with arguments:

```
>>> sum = lambda x, y: x+y
>>> diff = lambda x,y: x-y
>>> either(sum, diff, .5)(4, 6)
-2
>>> either(sum, diff, .5)(4, 6)
10
```

or perhaps

```
>>> f = either (sum, diff, .75)
>>> result = f(4,5)
```

Not that I think there's anything very useful about this, but maybe it's a little like what you're looking for?